# maven versions:set is not updating the referenced dependencies

Tags: maven

In my multi module project I have pom files defined in this way:

```
Parent
 pom.xml
   child 1
     pom.xml
   child 2
     pom.xml
   child 3
     pom.xml
```

Now I have dependencies defined in child 2 and 3 on child 1. When I run `mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=<new version>`, it updates all the project versions and dependencies in all the pom files (as expected) but not the dependencies in child 3. It does update project version to new version in child 3, but it should also update the dependencies to new version as well.

Here is the excerpt of my pom file for child 3 after I ran `versions:set`:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.xyz.abc</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.19</version>
</parent>
<groupId>com.xyz.abc.parent</groupId>
<artifactId>child3</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0.19</version>
<name>child3</name>
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>Common</groupId>
        <artifactId>Common</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.xyz.abc.parent</groupId>
        <artifactId>child1</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: You should add the relevant parts of your poms to help understanding.

Comment: Put that in your question and correctly format that.